# Can the Cauchy-Goursat Theorem be applied to show that $|\int_Cf(z)dz|=0$ if $f(z)=\frac{e^z}{i-sin(z)}$ and $C$ is the circle $|z|=1$?

Tags: complex-analysis

Can the Cauchy-Goursat Theorem be applied to show that $|\int_Cf(z)dz|=0$ if $f(z)=\frac{e^z}{i-sin(z)}$ and $C$ is the circle $|z|=1$? I'm pretty sure I need to find where $f(z)$ is analytic, so I need to find where $f(z)$ doesn't exist which is when $sin(z)=i$ but I'm unsure how to evaluate that. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hint: By using the definition of $\sin z$, $$\sin z = i \iff \frac{e^{iz} - e^{-iz}}{2i} = i$$ which will give you a quadratic equation in $e^{iz}$

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track, indeed we need to solve $\sin z = i$

Now

$$\sin z = i \iff \frac{e^{iz} - e^{-iz}}{2i} = i \iff e^{iz} - e^{-iz} = -2 \iff (e^{iz})^2 + 2 e^{iz} - 1 = 0$$

Solving the quadratic equation gives

$$e^{iz} = -1 \pm \sqrt{2}$$

Writing $z = x + iy$, we have

$$e^{-y + ix} = e^{-y} e^{ix} = \sqrt{2} - 1 \text{ or } -(\sqrt{2} + 1)$$

So we have

$$\begin{cases} x = 2 \pi k \\ y = -\log(\sqrt{2} - 1) \end{cases}
\text{ or } 
\begin{cases} x = \pi + 2 \pi k \\ y = -\log(\sqrt{2} + 1) \end{cases}$$

where $k \in \mathbb{Z}$

Since $|x| \le |z| \le 1$, the only possible solution of $\sin z = i$ inside $|z| = 1$ is $z = -\log(\sqrt{2} - 1)i$

Using a calculator, one can check $|-\log(\sqrt{2} - 1)i| = |\log(\sqrt{2} - 1)| < 1$

Next, we claim $-\log(\sqrt{2} - 1)i$ is a simple pole of $f$.

Firstly, both $e^z$ and $i - \sin z$ are entire.

Secondly, $e^{-\log(\sqrt{2} - 1)i} \ne 0$ since $|e^{-\log(\sqrt{2} - 1)i}| = 1$

Thirdly, $i - \sin(-\log(\sqrt{2} - 1)i) = 0$

Fourthly, $(i - \sin z)'(-\log(\sqrt{2} - 1)i) = -\cos(-\log(\sqrt{2} - 1)i) \ne 0$ since $\cos z = 0 \iff z = \frac{\pi}{2} + \pi k$ where $k \in \mathbb{Z}$

So $-\log(\sqrt{2} - 1)i$ is a simple pole of $f$ with
$$\underset{z = -\log(\sqrt{2} - 1)i}{\operatorname{Res}} f = \frac{e^{-\log(\sqrt{2} - 1)i}}{-\cos(-\log(\sqrt{2} - 1)i)} = -\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} e^{-\log(\sqrt{2} - 1)i}$$

since $$\cos(-\log(\sqrt{2} - 1) i) = \cosh(-\log(\sqrt{2} - 1)) = \frac{e^{-\log(\sqrt{2} - 1)} + e^{\log(\sqrt{2} - 1)}}{2} = \frac{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2} - 1} + \sqrt{2} - 1}{2} = \sqrt{2}$$

Finally, by Cauchy's residue theorem,

$$\int_C f = 2 \pi i \underset{z = -\log(\sqrt{2} - 1)i}{\operatorname{Res}} f = -\sqrt{2} \pi i e^{-\log(\sqrt{2} - 1)i}$$